# slice an array based on indeces

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, loops

I have the current HTML:

```
<div id="1-1">TITLE1</div>
<div id="1-2">TITLE2</div>
<div id="1-3">TITLE3</div>
<div id="1-4">TITLE4</div>
<div id="1-5">TITLE5</div>

<div class="topic">A1</div>
<div class="topic">B2</div>
<div class="topic">C3</div>
<div class="topic">D4</div>
<div class="topic">E5</div>
<div class="topic">F6</div>
<div class="topic">G7</div>
<div class="topic">H8</div>
<div class="topic">I9</div>
<div class="topic">J10</div>
<div class="topic">K11</div>
<div class="topic">L12</div>
<div class="topic">M13</div>
<div class="topic">N14</div>
<div class="topic">O15</div>
```

And I want to use JavaScript to create a `for loop` that will append the correct `.topic` nodes into the correct TITLE div based on this object:

```
all = {'1-1': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
       '1-2': ['D'],
       '1-3': ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
       '1-4': ['I', 'J'],
       '1-5': ['K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O']
      };
```

Where the loop will ideally result in:

```
<div id="1-1">TITLE1
<div class="topic">A1</div>
<div class="topic">B2</div>
<div class="topic">C3</div>
</div>

<div id="1-2">TITLE2
<div class="topic">D4</div>
</div>

<div id="1-3">TITLE3
<div class="topic">E5</div>
<div class="topic">F6</div>
<div class="topic">G7</div>
<div class="topic">H8</div>
</div>

<div id="1-4">TITLE4
<div class="topic">I9</div>
<div class="topic">J10</div>
</div>

<div id="1-5">TITLE5
<div class="topic">K11</div>
<div class="topic">L12</div>
<div class="topic">M13</div>
<div class="topic">N14</div>
<div class="topic">O15</div>
</div>
```

I've taken a stab at this by creating two arrays -- one of the "TITLE*" locations in `all` and another of how many "topics" should be in each slice

```
let header_position = [0,4,6,11,14]
let topics_between = [3,1,4,2,5]
```

I was trying to leverage this and find a pattern for the `for loop` so that I can use these array numbers  in order to put things in the right place but I can't seem to figure out the proper loop. Any help would be appreciated:

## Attempted Solution

```
for (i = 0; i < header_position.length; i++) {
  // i = 0 topics.slice(0,2)
  // i = 2 topics.slice(3,3)
  // i = 3 topics.slice(4,7)
  // i = 4 topics.slice(8,9)
  // i = 5 topics.slice(10,14)
  
  let currentslice = topics.slice(header_position[i] + 1, header_position[i + 1] - 2)
  
  if (i === 0) {
    currentslice = topics.slice(0, topics_between[i] - 1)
  }
  
  console.log(currentslice)
  currentslice.appendTo("#1-" + [i + 1])
}
```

This loop does not work as it stands, but I would appreciate any help or considerations in trying to get this logic functional!

Comment: Can you change the structure of the `all` array? I would go with an object, having the title `id`s as keys, and an array of the content identifiers as a value. Like `all = {'1-1': ['A', 'B', 'C'], ...};`. That would be relatively easy to iterate.

Comment: Hi @Teemu! I've changed the object based on your suggestion - thanks!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ov51ghp2/1/

Comment: Or even without the title ids: https://jsfiddle.net/ov51ghp2/1/ . If you've to maintain the order table manually, then an object might be a bit more comfortable to use, though. An ideal solution would be, that the topics would have a class identifying the title, it would be an O(n) loop to append the topics under the titles.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems pretty theorical... And looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

I assume your titles certainly will not be `TITLE1`, `TITLE2` and so on with some real content.

I suppose you managed to define the `all` array to have a start of organisation of your page... But from what's posted, I can't suggest any better way.

So if I just take the `all` and the `header_position` arrays as-is, the loop would use two *indexes*, one for the headers and one for the topics.

Have a look below and tell me if that answers your theorical question as well as your concrete need.

```js
let all = [ "TITLE1", "A", "B", "C", 
            "TITLE2", "D",
            "TITLE3", "E", "F", "G", "H",
            "TITLE4", "I", "J",
            "TITLE5", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O"]
            
let header_position = [0,4,6,11,14]
//let topics_between = [3,1,4,2,5]  // not used

let headerIndex = -1
let topicIndex = 0

for(i=0;i<all.length;i++){
  if(header_position.indexOf(i)>-1){
    headerIndex++
    continue
  }
  $(".header").eq(headerIndex).append($(".topic").eq(topicIndex))
  topicIndex++
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header" id="1-1">TITLE1</div>
<div class="header" id="1-2">TITLE2</div>
<div class="header" id="1-3">TITLE3</div>
<div class="header" id="1-4">TITLE4</div>
<div class="header" id="1-5">TITLE5</div>

<div class="topic">A1</div>
<div class="topic">B2</div>
<div class="topic">C3</div>
<div class="topic">D4</div>
<div class="topic">E5</div>
<div class="topic">F6</div>
<div class="topic">G7</div>
<div class="topic">H8</div>
<div class="topic">I9</div>
<div class="topic">J10</div>
<div class="topic">K11</div>
<div class="topic">L12</div>
<div class="topic">M13</div>
<div class="topic">N14</div>
<div class="topic">O15</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood, you want it to be split up by title. You can do this:

```js
let count = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
    if (all[i].includes("TITLE")) {
        let element = document.createElement("div");
        element.innerHTML = all[i];
        element.id = `1-${count + 1}`;
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        count++;
    } else {
        let element = document.createElement("div");
        element.className = "topic";
        element.innerHTML = `${all[i]}${i - count + 1}`;
        document.getElementById(`1-${count}`).appendChild(element);
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works.